# Import JSON/YAML into Postman from Swagger (OA 3.0.1)

Tags: import, automation, swagger, postman, openapi

There exist projects like [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/openapi-to-postman) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger2-postman-generator) that convert APIs in Swagger to Postman collections.

Is there a way to script importing the Postman collection JSON file into Postman?

To be clear, I am trying to *avoid* having to use the Postman GUI to do the import.

I want the whole process to be automated.

I am on a Windows environment.

Ideal goal: import directly from `https://myapi/v1/swagger.json` into Postman.

Even better: trigger on change.

Motivation: Postman always has latest-and-greatest API version.